# Failed to count the number of records in Hibernate:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, parameters, hql

I encountered a very urgly problem when I's trying to count the number of records using Hibernate. By debuging I get the HQL and related error:

HQL:

`SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalSize FROM UserAccount WHERE 1 = 1  AND role IN (:role_list)  AND agent.id = :agentId`

Set Parameter:

```
query.setParameter("role_list", parameter.getRoles());
query.setParameter("agentId", parameter.getAgentId());
```

Error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

I'm confused with that since It worked fine previously when I set its parameter with sequence instead of name. Can anybody give me ideas for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Stupid question, I should set collection parameter with the method of 'setParameterList'.

Comment: I guess you could simply remove your question! ;)